# Paypal Subscription + Custom Setup Fee

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

I need to setup an invoice in Paypal with:

- A subscription of 15, 20 or 25 USD a month
- With an initial setup fee of 15, 50 or 100 USD (This amount comes from a third party, I cannot predict it)

Can I achieve this with a single PayPal invoice?

Also need to achieve it with Stripe, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Stripe, you can add a setup fee to your subscription like this:

1. [Create the customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) using a token or source created by [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout).
2. [Create an invoice item](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) with the value of the setup fee.
3. [Create the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription).

When the subscription is created, a first invoice will be created immediately and it will include the item created in step 2 in addition to the subscription's base cost.

Comment: Thanks, seems straightforward, you wouldn't happen to know the way to accomplish the same with PayPal?

Answer (score 1):

With PayPal, there is a setup_fee variable you can add to the Billing Plan by specifying it in the merchant_preferences object.

Here is the integration information on Billing Plans and Billing Agreements. Click on Create a Plan to see an example which uses setup_fee.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/#integration-steps